# Deeplink from a Website to an Action on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to create buttons on my website which redirect the user to a Action on Google. Are these kinds of deeplinks possible with AoG?

Example:
Let's say I have a furniture E-Commerce shop and I would like to provide customers step-by-step instructions to put the furniture together. For this purpose I create an Action on Google.

If a users looks at the detail page of a chair on my website, there should be a button "Assemble the chair with Google Assisant". Basically this would deeplink him into the Google Assistant on his device.

Is this already possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is known as [Action Links](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/action-links). You can configure them in the Actions Console, and you can pass specific intents and parameters in the URL.

The format is like this `https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke[/$action_id][?intent=$intent&param.$param=$value][&$utm_param=$utm_value]`